# Nothing renders after porting to OpenGL 3.3

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am at a point where I think I am done porting my application to work with GL 3.3 and a #version 330 shader.
However, I get a black screen (from glClear()) but don't see anything wrong. I'll try to give a walkthrough through my code.

This is my rendering function:

```
void render() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    applyCameraPerspective();
    glUseProgram(prog);
    setUniforms();

    for (ObjectList::iterator it = objectList.begin(); it != objectList.end(); it++) {
        GLuint usedTexture = glTextureList.find((*it)->getTextureName())->second;
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, usedTexture);
        glUniform1ui(textureLoc, 0);
        (*it)->render();
        //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    glPopMatrix();
    frameCount++;
}
```

usedTexture is the GLuint texture index.

*it is an object of class RenderObject, which's render() function looks like so:

```
void render() {
    if (totalTriangleCount > 0) {

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

        //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        //glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        //glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
        //glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
        //glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalTriangleCount * 3);

        //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        //glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        //glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

You can see here glXXXPointer()-functions and client state toggles being removed to work with the new version. When I uncomment them, I, strangely, get geometry rendered, but with what looks like uninterpolated texture coordinates. However, the point of the layout qualifier (see further below) should be that these calls are no longer required.

The objects have had a initToGL()-function called beforehand, which looks like this:

```
void initToGL(GLuint positionLoc, GLuint normalLoc, GLuint texCoordLoc) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    totalTriangleCount = 0;

    for (FaceList::iterator it = faceList.begin(); it != faceList.end(); it++) {
        totalTriangleCount += (*it)->getTriangleCount();
    }

    // Per triangle: 36 bytes for position, 36 for normal, 24 for texture coordinates (32 per vertex)
    UINT bytesNeeded = 3 * (12 + 12 + 8) * totalTriangleCount;
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesNeeded, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0)); // Position
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12)); // Normal
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24)); // Texture coordinates

    GLintptr currentOffset = 0;

    for (FaceList::iterator fIt = faceList.begin(); fIt != faceList.end(); fIt++) {
        std::list<std::vector<UINT>> indicesList = (*fIt)->getTriangleVertexIndices();
        for (std::list<std::vector<UINT>>::iterator triIt = indicesList.begin(); triIt != indicesList.end(); triIt++) {
            // Get Vertex positions
            Vector3f vertex1 = (*fIt)->getVertex(triIt->at(0));
            Vector3f vertex2 = (*fIt)->getVertex(triIt->at(1));
            Vector3f vertex3 = (*fIt)->getVertex(triIt->at(2));

            // Calculate normal; keep in mind these vertices are clockwise!
            Vector3f normal = (vertex3 - vertex1).crossProduct(vertex2 - vertex1).normalize();

            // Get texture coordinates
            Vector2f textureCoordinate1 = (*fIt)->getTextureCoordinates(triIt->at(0));
            Vector2f textureCoordinate2 = (*fIt)->getTextureCoordinates(triIt->at(1));
            Vector2f textureCoordinate3 = (*fIt)->getTextureCoordinates(triIt->at(2));

            // Vertex 1
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &vertex1);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &normal);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 8, (GLvoid*) &textureCoordinate1);
            currentOffset += 8;

            // Vertex 2
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &vertex2);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &normal);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 8, (GLvoid*) &textureCoordinate2);
            currentOffset += 8;

            // Vertex 3
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &vertex3);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 12, (GLvoid*) &normal);
            currentOffset += 12;
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentOffset, 8, (GLvoid*) &textureCoordinate3);
            currentOffset += 8;
        }
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Here, the parameters given to this function are the same ones retrieved from the shader (see further below).
The only change here is the addition of the 3 calls to glVertexAttribPointer().

applyCameraPerspective():

```
void applyCameraPerspective() {
    glRotatef(cam->getPitch(), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(cam->getRoll(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(cam->getYaw(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(-cam->x(), -cam->y(), -cam->z());
}
```

This still relies on OpenGL's matrix stack.

setUniforms():

```
void setUniforms() {

    GLfloat m[16];

    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &m[0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0]);

    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &m[0]);
    //for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    //  for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    //      std::cout << std::showpoint << m[4 * x + y] << std::noshowpoint << "  " ;
    //  }
    //  std::cout << std::endl;
    //}
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0]);

    // Error: GL_NORMAL_MATRIX is not a thing. :-(
    //glGetFloatv(GL_NORMAL_MATRIX, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0]);

    // HACKHACK: As long as we don't do scale transformations (which we don't) we will be fine doing just this.
    m[12] = 0;
    m[13] = 0;
    m[14] = 0;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(normalMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0]);
}
```

You can see here I have added output to test the correctness of the model view matrix. It is as expected.

My code for loading textures has not changed. My code for loading the shader program is executed before uploading objects and looks like so:

```
bool setupShader() {
    bool success = true;

    // Vertex shader
    vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    std::string vsString = TextFileReader().readWhole("Shader/basic_fog.vert");
    const char* vsChars = vsString.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsChars, NULL);
    std::cout << "Compiling vertex shader." << std::endl;
    glCompileShader(vs);
    success &= printShaderInfo(vs);

    // Fragment shader
    fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    std::string fsString = TextFileReader().readWhole("Shader/basic_fog.frag");
    const char* fsChars = fsString.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsChars, NULL);
    std::cout << "Compiling fragment shader." << std::endl;
    glCompileShader(fs);
    success &= printShaderInfo(fs);

    // Bundle them into a program
    prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, vs);
    glAttachShader(prog, fs);

    glBindFragDataLocation(prog, 0, "fragColor");
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    success &= printProgramInfo(prog);

    if (success) {
        // These all are GLuints
        positionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "position");
        normalLoc = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "normal");
        texCoordLoc = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "texCoordinates");

        projectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "projectionMatrix");
        modelViewMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "modelViewMatrix");
        normalMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "normalMatrix");

        textureLoc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "colorTexture");
    }

    return success;
}
```

Notice that I never glBindAttribLocation(), because I use the layout qualifier (see below).
This function returns true for the following shader code which I use.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragPosition;

layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 fragNormal;

layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoordinates;
layout(location = 2) out vec2 fragTexCoordinates;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, normalMatrix;

void main() {
    fragPosition = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1)).xyz;
    fragNormal = (normalMatrix * vec4(normal, 1)).xyz;
    fragTexCoordinates = vec2(texCoordinates);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 textureCoordinates;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D colorTexture;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture2D(colorTexture, textureCoordinates);
}
```

I have tried setting fragColor to just red: No results. Not a single pixel runs through the fragment shader.

That is a lot of code. I'd greatly appreciate someone taking a look at it, especially with regards to simply using certain functions incorrectly.

Comment: Are you trying to use a core profile context?

Comment: I'm trying to understand and use the new paradigms. If something proves useful which isn't core profile, but not deprecated, either, I might just use it.

Comment: well. The difference between core and compatibility profiles is that in core, the deprecated stuff is actually removed. If I interpret your comment correctly, you are using a compatibility profile. Your code will definitifely not work in a core profile.

Comment: I use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) for getting a context to work with, and [it apparantly uses compatibility profile](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6926.msg45731#msg45731). What exactly do you see is deprecated if I may ask? (even if it is not the cause of the problem)

Comment: You should start small, and not jump immediately into something that radically changes how GLSL programs work (e.g. Separate Shader Objects). In fact, I do not even see any pipeline objects or other necessary setup in order to use SSOs. Did you just insert that pre-processor directive for fun? :P

Comment: If I remove it I get the following shader compile error: "layout(location) requires "#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable" before use.

Comment: Well of course it does, do not use `layout (location = ...)` for anything but `in` varyings in the vertex shader stage. Otherwise you are just making life more difficult for yourself. GLSL is designed to assign those automatically, and this was ONLY changed when Separate Shader Objects were introduced. Since you are not using Separate Shader Objects, stop doing that and remove the `#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects` line.

Comment: It sounded attractive to me since I could use different names for variables in vertex and fragment shader and still have them map to each other. :F Removing that for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most obvious problems with your code is the mishmash of deprecated OpenGL, like the fixed function matrix stack and modern features like self defined uniforms. Stuff like this:

```
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &m[0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0]);
```

which indicates that you're using old-style FFP matrix functions to calculate the matrix, query it from OpenGL and feed it back into a uniform. You really shouldn't do this. Use a real matrix math library instead, like GLM or Eigen.

Then of course `glEnableClientState` will not work with modern generic vertex attributes. I do not see any calls to `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, so if those are missing it's no surprise that noting gets drawn.

Comment: That mechanic somehow got past me unnoticed. Thanks. Also got to add to this, since I am using VBOs (generated with glGenBuffers()) instead of VAOs, the glEnableVertexAttribArray()-calls need to happen in the render()-function after binding the buffer, because the information given by those is stored in VAOs (which are deprecated in GL 3.1+) but not in VBOs. ([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/when-to-use-vertex-array-and-when-to-use-vbo))

Comment: @Zyl: VAOs are not deprecated but a requirement in later OpenGL versions. In fact in OpenGL-4 and later you must create and bind at least a catch all VAO for anything actually to work.

Comment: The guy in provided source says "Vertex Arrays: These are available in OpenGL prior to 3.0, deprecated in 3.0, and gone in 3.1+. OpenGL ES supports them (OpenGL ES 2 does not).". If now VAs and VAOs are again different things then make me smarter, lol.

Comment: @Zyl: This is about Client Side Vertex Arrays, which is something very different than a VAO. A vertex array object (VAO) holds the binding state between VBOs and vertex attributes. So instead of making several `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` calls you just make a single VAO `glBindVertexArray` call. Also note that VBOs are still vertex arrays, they're just no longer client side, but server side.

Comment: That actually explained a lot and I got a VAO working now. I am still a bit unsure about what state changes are "recorded". Is there a comprehensive list?